# how to collect 100 accelerometer reading in just one second

Tags: android, accelerometer

hello all I am developing an android application that collect the acceleration in three direction (x,y,z) and i need trusted code that allow me to collect 100 reading exactly in one second please help me .
best regards

Comment: what do you mean by android-emultator ???

Comment: trusted code? use a thread or something alike to measure time then read in accerlero data

Comment: could you please give me hint , or some code to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

When you use SensorManager.registerListener() you can set the rate parameter to your needs. The rate is the delay in microseconds between events.

Comment: However, that does not ensure that you will get 100 readings in a second. All you are doing is not introducing your own delays into the process.

Comment: could you please tell me more precisely how to do that ?